# property is being triggered before ngOnInit() in component

Tags: javascript, user-interface, angular6, frontend

I'm new to Angular and I tried some code where the property set is being triggered before the ngOnInit().

```
export class App implements OnInit{
  isTriggered = false;

  constructor(){
    ...
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.isTriggered = true;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how this works but `isTriggered = false;` is getting triggered first before the debugger moves to `this.isTriggered = true;`

Can someone explain me why this is happening and whats the approach to trigger `this.isTriggered = true;` from ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious actually. To invoke *ngOnInit* you need an instance of App class. When you create an instance all declared fields are initialized first.

Comment: I have same piece of code in local workspace where this.isTriggered = true; is being triggered first and in deployed code isTriggered = false; this is being triggered. I'm not sure why this is happening. Sorry for not being clear in the question.

Comment: Hmm, sounds very strange. How did you check that? Are you sure that no body else touch that field before ngOnInit will be invoked?

Comment: I checked every line and the code is same line to line

Comment: Actually, I have no idea for now. Could you please try to reproduce it with [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ngOnInit` is an Angular lifecycle method,  whereas the `isTriggered = false` is a class property, native to Javascript, same as if you had placed it inside the constructor.

In the old way of doing things before Javascript Classes even came around, it might've been more obvious.

```
export function App() {
   this.isTriggered = false;
   this.ngOnInit = function() { };
}
```

Seen this way, it's pretty obvious that `isTriggered = false` will be invoked immediately upon creating a `new App()` vs. `ngOnInit` which will only be invoked by something calling `ngOnInit` after the `new` object is already created.

Angular lifecycle methods will happen on Angular's framework timing, meaning it's going to happen sometime after that class is initialized. During the initialization of that class, the class property will be set, hence why you see the debugger go to that line first.

Comment: Nicely explained Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `isTriggered = false`, that is the same as doing it as initializing it as if it was a part of the constructor. ngOnInit happens afterwards, so that's why you're getting it set to false and then to true.

You can declare `isTriggered` without assigning it a value simply by removing `= false;` and then only in ngOnInit assign it to true if that's what you're looking to do.